# Eclipse git cannot finish rebase

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am trying to do an interactive re base using the EGit plugin in eclipse.
When i select continue on the re base eclipse shows the following error
.git\rebase-merge\done (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: What happens when you try it via terminal?

Comment: It was still not doing a proper re base.

Comment: can you provide more details like output of `git status` and full output of `git rebase continue`

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem was that, i was using the side menu options. When i tried to rebase from the git interactive rebase perspective it was ok. This happens on Eclipse Mars.

Comment: Happens on Neon also